# Difference between += and append for adding single item to an Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Going through the basics of Swift, I noticed that there are two ways of adding items to an array.

One way is using the `.append` method, another is using the `+=` operator (which allows for the adding of > 2 item arrays).

Is there any difference between using `+=` and `.append` when you only want to add a single item to the array?

```
fooArray.append("Bar")
```

versus

```
fooArray += ["Bar"]
```

Comment: I would assume that the first option is negligibly faster, because in the second method you are creating an array on top of allocating a string

Answer (score 12):

Both options do the exact same thing - add a value to an array, yet `+=` will allow for adding more than one value while `.append()` will only allow adding one value

Here's some code that tests which one is faster for adding a single value

```
var array: [String] = []
var array2: [String] = []

let time1 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

for i in 0...1000000{
    array += ["foobar"]
}

let time2 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
let dif1 = time2 - time1


let time3 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

for i in 0...1000000{
    array2.append("foobar")
}

let time4 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
let dif2 = time4 - time3
```

Testing this on an iPhone 6s, `dif1` was **1.47393365859985**, and `dif2` was **0.385605080127716** which is a difference of **1.0883285785** seconds for one million repetitions. (the average time for 100 runs)

This means that for only one repetition, the difference between the two is that `.append` will be about 0.000001088 seconds, or 1.088 microseconds faster than using `+=`.

In the end, it really doesn't matter which you're using to append one value - it's just personal preference *(obviously, if you need to add a million values to an array, you should use `.append()` as it will be noticeably faster)*

[Vikingosegundo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106435/vikingosegundo) has been very helpful in writing this answer, and [as per what he said](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34700920/34701028#comment57148712_34701028), you could use

```
func +=<T>(inout left:[T], right: T) -> [T]{
  left.append(right)
  return left
}
```

to get the best of both worlds - this will effectively turn `array += value` into `array.append(value)` (I believe this used to be a feature in older Swift versions, but was later removed)

Comment: did u use a playground?

Comment: Than your numbers are not very expressive. The storyboards daren't compiled with most performance features turned on.

Comment: *Why create an array if you'll only be storing one value in it?* because of readability. I find `list += [a]` much more readable than `list.append(a)`, or `list += [a,b]` more readable than `list.appendContentsOf([a,b])`. both codes perform so fast that it doesn't matter for 99.9%of the applications we deal with in cocoa.

Comment: btw: I doubt that your numbers are very correct still. certain system events could influence the timing. probably you should run the test you have now several times — maybe 100 or 1000 times — collect the numbers and take the median. But surely the tendency is covered already.

Comment: better do 100*100,000 than 10*1,000,000

Comment: btw: you could use `func +=<T>(inout left:[T], right: T) -> [T] { left.append(right); return left }` to allow `list += a` to append with an addition assignment operator without using an intermediate array.

Comment: nah, the question is too vague. I don't like answering those.

Comment: Well, as swift is open source, I try to find the implementation. but so far I don't understand the project structure.

Comment: according tho [this file](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a30ae2bf55e21859418da6b8cd28273d5b71719c/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb), the method `appendContentsOf()` uses the `+=` operator, while `append()` does not.

Answer (score 3):

## How does [`+=`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e3a4147ac94e55fcab1d14e949f572b53d9eb638/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L1010) work?

[`Array`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Sa) conforms to [CollectionType](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs14CollectionType) so when you invoke [+=](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e3a4147ac94e55fcab1d14e949f572b53d9eb638/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L1010) the following happens:

```
/// Extend `lhs` with the elements of `rhs`.
public func += <Element, C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == Element>
  (inout lhs: ${Self}<Element>, rhs: C) {
  let rhsCount = numericCast(rhs.count) as Int

  let oldCount = lhs.count
  let capacity = lhs.capacity
  let newCount = oldCount + rhsCount

  // Ensure uniqueness, mutability, and sufficient storage.  Note that
  // for consistency, we need unique lhs even if rhs is empty.
  lhs.reserveCapacity(
    newCount > capacity ?
    max(newCount, _growArrayCapacity(capacity))
    : newCount)

  (lhs._buffer.firstElementAddress + oldCount).initializeFrom(rhs)
  lhs._buffer.count = newCount
}
```

## How does [`append`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e3a4147ac94e55fcab1d14e949f572b53d9eb638/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#:681) work?

```
/// Append `newElement` to the ${Self}.
///
/// - Complexity: Amortized ${O1}.
public mutating func append(newElement: Element) {
  _makeUniqueAndReserveCapacityIfNotUnique()
  let oldCount = _getCount()
  _reserveCapacityAssumingUniqueBuffer(oldCount)
  _appendElementAssumeUniqueAndCapacity(oldCount, newElement: newElement)
}
```

The implementation of `+=` is a generalized implementation of `append` (I will not dig into each call inside `append` but feel free to check it), and, for that reason, `append` should be a tiny better when dealing with only one element.

So I'd go with whichever one you think will suit your code base better, consistency is key and if the difference between the performance of `+=` and `append` is causing you problems you're probably doing something **really wrong**. As a food for thought:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- [DonaldKnuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DonaldKnuth)

### [Fun fact](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e3a4147ac94e55fcab1d14e949f572b53d9eb638/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#:681)

```
public mutating func appendContentsOf<C : CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == Element>(newElements: C) {
  self += newElements
}
```

**Edit:** As an *addendum* I personally like [vikingosegundo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106435/vikingosegundo)'s proposal and would use it to keep consistency using `+=` everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Apple.

> You can add a new item to the end of an array by calling the array’s append(_:) method:

```
shoppingList.append("Flour") // shoppingList now contains 3 items, and someone is making pancakes
```

> Alternatively, append an array of one or more compatible items with the addition assignment operator (+=):

```
shoppingList += ["Baking Powder"] // shoppingList now contains 4 items
shoppingList += ["Chocolate Spread", "Cheese", "Butter"] // shoppingList now contains 7 items
```

So basically with the `append` method there is an only option that you can append one item. But with the `+=` operator you can append multiple items as an array.

Comment: arr.appendContentsOf(newElements) should work as well.